# DevExpress Scheduler is not filled with data from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, devexpress, scheduler

I want to fill XtraScheduler with data from database stored procedure. The scheduler is filled only with one record and I cant understand why. The stored procedure is correct and returns 8 records.

Here's my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Reservations]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT  
        HallSeat.HallGroupID, Color, Price, SeatRow, SeatRowLetter, 
        SeatNumber, SeatNumberLetter, ReservationTime, IsReserved 
    FROM 
        HallSeat
    LEFT JOIN 
        HallGroup ON HallGroup.HallGroupID = HallSeat.HallGroupID
    LEFT JOIN 
        Hall ON HallGroup.HallID = Hall.HallID  
    WHERE 
        (IsReserved = 'true') 
END
```

I assigned *Appointments Data Source* in Scheduler to reservationsBindingSource which represents my stored procedure, and I chose the mappings like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6btH.png

In the code I fill reservationDataAdapter like this (it was created automatically):

```
this.reservationsTableAdapter.Fill(this.filharmonijaDataSet1.Reservations);
```

Somehow the scheduler always shows only one record, even though there's a lot more... Where is the problem?..

Comment: are you sure that you are not missing any property?? did you set the Appointments Data Source and Resource data source properties also??? If you want to create these in custom way then use another approach to populate the scheduler control.

Comment: Why then it fills that one record even without resources? I want to test it first without resources

Answer (score 0):

As I suspect about your code that you are missing few thing while binding XtraScheduler with SQL database. You need to become familiar with how DevExpress works and For the scheduler the only thing you need to do different is to understand the calendar mapping for the Appointments Data Source and the Resources Data Source.

I suggest you to go through documentation that how [Data Binding](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument8386) works with Scheduler control.

If you are assigning data source at design time then follow below documentation link for reference and then modify your data source accordingly:

[Lesson 5 - Bind a Scheduler to MS SQL Database at Design Time](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2278)

It requires to set the two properties to display appointments:

1. Appointments Data Source
2. Resources Data Source

You can also create appointments or resources in custom way. Leave the Resource Data Source blank and then placed this create resources manually at the Form_Load event or some where else:

```
ApptResourcesBO.fillAll();
Object resourceID = new Object();
DataTable dtSyatemUsers = ApptResourcesBO.getAll();
foreach (DataRow drUser in dtSyatemUsers.Rows)
{
resourceID = Convert.ToInt32(drUser["apr_UniqueID"]);
Resource resourceUser = new Resource(resourceID, Convert.ToString(drUser["apr_ResourceName"]));
schedulerStorage.Resources.Add(resourceUser);
}
```

You can also add an Appointment to the XtraScheduler programmatically. Please review the following code:

```
    Appointment apt = schedulerControl1.Storage.CreateAppointment(AppointmentType.Normal);
    apt.Start = DateTime.Today.AddHours(8);
    apt.Duration = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
    apt.Subject = "Subject";
    apt.Description = "Description";
    schedulerControl1.Storage.Appointments.Add(apt);
```

References:
[Bind data to xtrascheduler programatically with resource.](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q553547)

Hope this help..